# Total (stochastic) orders for univariate distributions on compact set

Tags: distributions, stochastic-ordering

Let $[\underline{x},\bar{x}] = X \in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ be a compact set and $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all CDFs $F$ on $X$.

What **total** stochastic orders can I define on $\mathcal{F}$? (see *Wikipedia definitions* for [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) and [stochastic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering))

Notice I read on stochastic ordering wikipedia's page, intro paragraph, the following:

> These are **usually** partial orders, so that one random variable
> $A$ may be neither stochastically greater than, less
> than nor equal to another random variable $B$.

I tried to make a search for a total stochastic order relation by giving a quick look into the book by *Shaked Moshe* and *Shanthikumar George* "*Stochastic Orders*". Unfortunately, without success.

The only total stochastic orders I can come up with on $\mathcal{F}$ are the "trivial" ones like comparing means, standard deviations etc ... (supposing those moments actually exist). Is there anything richer than that? (like an alternative definition for stochastic dominance, which is however a partial order)

I must also say I'm from another field (economics) so it's possible I'm missing something here.

Comment: Your examples are not total orders, because they are not antisymmetric.  The set of all distributions on $X$ does not support any total order unless $X$ is a point.

Comment: Thanks for this remark, point taken. Can you refer me to any reference regarding the second part of your comment?

Comment: These random variables form a real vector space and no real vector space of dimension greater than 1 supports a total order (in a way that respects the vector space structure).  Any good textbook in real analysis should include a proof.